# stub any_instance using Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocha.js, minitest, doorkeeper

How can I do the following without using any_instance from Mocha? I just want to test a protected Controller as [described here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Testing-protected-controllers) without using Rspec.

```
class PortfoliosControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  setup do
    @portfolio = portfolios(:p2)
    user = @portfolio.user

    token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.create!(application_id: 'minitest',
                                            resource_owner_id: user.id)
    PortfoliosController.any_instance.stubs(:doorkeeper_token).returns(token)
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you seen this solution for stubbing with no libraries? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10329105/356060

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to stub any instance of PortfoliosController, just the instance that the test is using. This is available in the `@controller` variable, as explained in the [ActionController::TestCase documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html#class-ActionController::TestCase-label-Special+instance+variables).

```
class PortfoliosControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  setup do
    @portfolio = portfolios(:p2)
    user = @portfolio.user

    token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.create!(application_id: 'minitest',
                                            resource_owner_id: user.id)
    @controller.stubs(:doorkeeper_token).returns(token)
  end
end
```

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method `stubs' for #<PortfoliosController:0x007fdce8a49eb8>` now I guess, I just need the correct way to stub with Minitest

Comment: If you have required Mocha then `.stubs` will be available. That error makes me think you haven't loaded Mocha.

Comment: not requiring Mocha is part of my question. How can I do it using only Minitest?

Comment: since controller tests are integration tests in rails 5, this won't work anymore. #sadpanda

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend checking out [this gem](https://github.com/codeodor/minitest-stub_any_instance). Would allow you to do something like...

```
class PortfoliosControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def cool_test
    PortfoliosController.stub_any_instance(:doorkeeper_token, token) do
      # Assert whatever you were going to assert
    end
  end
end
```

kind of nice not to have to worry about `setup` either.

Answer (score 1):

'no Mocha' version of 'blowmage' answer

```
 class PortfoliosControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  setup do
    @portfolio = portfolios(:p2)
    user = @portfolio.user

    token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.create!(application_id: 'minitest',
                                            resource_owner_id: user.id)
    @controller.stub(:doorkeeper_token,token) do
      #do your tests
    end
  end
end
```

see http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/4.2.0/Object:stub