# How to test a Rails 5 helper that relies on Devise signed_in? helper, with Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise

Given the following Rails 5 helper method, that relies on the Devise helper `signed_in?`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def sign_in_or_out_link
    if signed_in?
      link_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
    else
      link_to 'Sign In', new_user_session_path
    end
  end
end
```

And the desire to test that the helper returns a particular link based on the signed-in status of the user:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  test 'returns Sign Out when signed in' do
    assert_match 'Sign Out', sign_in_or_out_link
  end

  test 'returns Sign In when not signed in' do
    assert_match 'Sign In', sign_in_or_out_link
  end
end
```

The test runner raises an error:
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'signed_in?' for #<ApplicationHelperTest:...>`.

While we can stub the method within the test:

```
class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  def signed_in?
    true
  end
  # ..
```

How do I re-stub the `signed_in?` method such that it returns `false` for the second test?

Comment: Basically, this question is: 'how do i stub in mini-test?'. Try some of the answers in this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211086/how-do-i-stub-things-in-minitest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stub all 3 methods and use an instance variable to control the value for two different states:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  def signed_in?
    @signed_in
  end

  def new_user_session_path
    '/users/new'
  end

  def destroy_user_session_path
    '/users/new'
  end

  test 'returns Sign Out when signed in' do
    @signed_in = true
    assert_match 'Sign Out', sign_in_or_out_link
  end

  test 'returns Sign In when not signed in' do
    @signed_in = false
    assert_match /Sign In/, sign_in_or_out_link
  end

end
```

Both tests pass:

```
~/codebases/tmp/rails-devise master*
❯ rake test
Run options: --seed 28418

# Running:

..

Finished in 0.007165s, 279.1347 runs/s, 558.2694 assertions/s.
2 runs, 4 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```