# How do I mock an "unless" method for rails using minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code that I am trying to mock 'myerror' scenario:

```
class Hello < ApplicationRecord


def first_method
    [{:myid=>1}, {:myid=>2}]
  end

  def second_method
    puts self.first_method
    return nil unless self.first_method
    self.first_method.first
  end

  def third_method
    puts self.second_method.nil? # true
    raise "myerror" unless self.second_method
    puts self.second_method.nil? # true
    self.second_method[:myid]
  end
end
```

In order to ensure the error happens I need to set "first_method" to nil and in my test (using minitest) I have:

```
require 'test_helper'

class HelloTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test '#hello_is_normal' do
    h = hellos(:one)
    h.first_method
    h.second_method
    h.third_method
  end



test '#hello_example_should_fail' do
    mock = Minitest::Mock.new
    mock.expect :first_method, nil
    mock.expect :second_method, nil
    mock.expect :nil?, true
    mock.expect :nil?, true

    h = hellos(:one)
    h.stub :second_method, mock do
      puts h.third_method
  end
```

end
    end

But It doesn't seem to be working as third_method doesn't result in 'myerror' getting raised.

Comment: is the syntax even correct in your test?

Comment: It should be `mock.expect :something, nil` right? Why don't you put a breakpoint in the `mymethod` and see what's going on?

Comment: @lacostenycoder: You mean the second to last line? No, that is definitely a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: oooh. sorry for the bad example. I've updated it to make it (hopefully) clearer.

Comment: `unless` is a keyword - not a method. Which means that an "unless method" is just gibberish. Just create a less abstracted example that demonstrates the problem that you are actually trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your function call of `mc.mymethod` within the block is returning the mock object which was not given the functionality of the actual `mymethod` function.  That is what this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211086/how-do-i-stub-things-in-minitest#14204600) would indicate.

I'm not sure if you actually want to stub this method at all.  Perhaps just use a let statement to set `something` to `nil` then run `mc.mymethod` on the actual mc.mymethod outside of any stub code block and test that.

That should yield the **exception** you expect.

Comment: This line `puts h.third_method # #<Minitest::Mock:0x0000561d744d4030>` shows you are asking h.third_method to return the mock object.  That is what `h.stub :third_method, mock do` does.

Comment: If I don't call it then the third_method never gets called. See edits