# How to stub a ruby method ensuring that it exists in Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, minitest

Contrary to the [documentation](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest#stubs) on `.stubs`, it seems that I'm able to stub a method that doesn't exist.

Considering the following code:

```
class DependencyClass
  def self.method_to_be_stubbed
    'hello'
  end
end

class TestMethodClass
  def self.method_being_tested
    DependencyClass.method_to_be_stubbed
  end
end

class StubbedMissingMethodTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test '#method_being_tested should return value from stub' do
    assert_equal 'hello', TestMethodClass.method_being_tested

    DependencyClass.stubs(:method_to_be_stubbed).returns('goodbye')

    assert_equal 'goodbye', TestMethodClass.method_being_tested
  end
end
```

In this example, `DependencyClass.stubs(:method_to_be_stubbed).returns('goodbye')` works as expected because `#method_to_be_stubbed` exists on `DependencyClass`. However, if I were to change `#method_to_be_stubbed` to a class instance method of `DependencyClass` as follows:

```
class DependencyClass
  def method_to_be_stubbed
    'hello'
  end
end

class StubbedMissingMethodTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test '#method_being_tested should return value from stub' do
    assert_equal 'hello', TestMethodClass.method_being_tested

    # despite the method not existing on the class,
    # instead on the instance - yet it still works?
    DependencyClass.stubs(:method_to_be_stubbed).returns('goodbye')

    assert_equal 'goodbye', TestMethodClass.method_being_tested
  end
end
```

My stub for `#method_to_be_stubbed` maintains the class method on `DependencyClass`, despite it not existing any longer. Is the expected behaviour not for the `.stubs` call to fail, since the method being stubbed does not exist?

Comment: Is that your actual code? the documentation you linked have a `.stub` method, not a `.stubs` method. I also cant' find that `returns` method. Are you using some extension?

Comment: @arieljuod I actually flagged this question for closure due to duplication from https://stackoverflow.com/q/7211086/3157745. I got confused between `.stubs` which behaves similarly with `.expects`, but shouldn't be confused with `.stub` which is different altogether (and happened to be what I was searching for).

Answer (score 1):

> Is the expected behaviour not for the .stubs call to fail, since the method being stubbed does not exist?

No, expected behaviour is not to fail. Here's why. You're not stubbing a method. You're stubbing a response to a *message*. For example, you have this line in your code: `user.name`. This means you're sending message `age` to object `user`. The easiest/most common way to teach `user` to handle message `age` is to ensure that it has an instance method called `age`. But there are other ways too. You could make user respond to age with method_missing. As far as ruby is concerned, this is just as valid.

Therefore, it would be wrong for minitest to check for method's existence here.

Comment: Can you clarify what 'messages are handled by methods of the same name' means? I could validate that the method exists through `DependencyClass.respond_to?(:method_to_be_stubbed)`, but I figure `.stubs` would at least check what I'm overriding before overriding it.

Comment: @Xenyal: Say, you have this line in your code: `user.name`. This means you're sending message `age` to object `user`. The easiest/most common way to teach `user` to handle message `age` is to ensure that it has an instance method called `age`. But, as I mentioned, you could make `user` respond to `age` with `method_missing`. As far as ruby is concerned, this is just as valid.

Comment: What if we consider an example that uses dependency injection where `user` is an input, and we rely on a library function of the class to retrieve the `age` attr? (eg. `self.get_user_name(user)`) Also, I believe class instance method stubbing does actually check for existence on the instance. How come class methods behave differently?

Comment: @Xenyal: "I believe class instance method stubbing does actually check for existence on the instance" - does it, though?

Comment: I apologize, that was my misconception (It does not).

Comment: Alternatively, it seems that Minitest `SomeClass.stub :method` does in fact check for the method to exist on the class, otherwise it raises a `NameError`. However, it's usage does differ from that of a mock since 1. there isn't an obvious way of validating the `.with` parameters, and 2. there isn't an obvious way for the code to result in a `.raises(SomeError)`. Ref: https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest/mock.rb#L212